# Alinhamento CSS

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte painel:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando alinhar os gráficos dentro da `div` a partir da classe `alinha-chart` mas sem sucesso. Quando coloco um `left: 33%` e `right: 33%` ele fica centralizado, mas como esperado, zoa no mobile. Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu código HTML **editado:

```
<div class="portlet-body row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="nome-rv"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?=$_SESSION['
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p100 orange big">
                            <span>100%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>                                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PISO</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p82 big">
                            <span>82%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>META</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered tabela-meta">             
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="grafico-situacao">
                        <div class="c100 p63 green big">
                            <span>63%</span>
                            <div class="slice">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="fill"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SUPERMETA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-sm-12` -> esse cara indica que em telas menores a `div` ocupará a linha toda, acredito que seja isso. 

(https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)
Dá uma sacada nesse link e vê se ajuda.

Comment: sim @rLinhares, porem gostaria de alinhar a div c100 com a tabela, dentro do grid do bootstrap

Comment: experimenta colocar tanto a `c100` quanto a `table` dentro de uma `<div class="row">`

Isso vai forçar a quebra de linha (não vai ser por conta do tamanho da tela) e pode evitar esse alinhamento bugado.

Comment: @rLinhares sem sucesso

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso eu faria um tabela com 1 `<tr>`e 3 `<td>` e colocaria dentro da `div` principal embaixo da `div` do nome :

```
<div class="portlet-body row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="nome-rv"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?=$_SESSION['nomeCompleto']?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

E colocaria dentro de cada `<td>`a bola de porcentagem com a descrição embaixo.

Comment: tentei da sua forma mas não consegui alinhar. Fiz algumas modificações sobre a sua sugestão pois creio q atendem mais ao layout, editei na pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a class `text-center` do próprio bootstrap para centralizar os gráficos, uma vez que eles dentro do `span`:

```
class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center" -> alinha-chart é realmente necessário aqui?
```

Se não se alinhar e defina uma largura ou uma largura máxima para as `divs`
que contém os gráficos e faça elas alinharem pelo CSS:

```
margin-left: auto
margin-right: auto
```